# Properly call/fetch information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-4, react-redux

I could use some guidance/nudge/light on an issue i’m having.  I am trying to figure out a way to create fetchUserImg, so that it can display user profile picture. Initially, the user’s ID number comes from the event’s host_id number. So basically the component should 1) grab event’s information(including the host_id) 2) pass that host_id into fetchUserImg to grab the user’s profile picture. But I am running into a problem that i’ve been trying to tackle. I’ve done a good amount of search, and while I found similar situations, I cannot replicate the solution to work on this instance.  I’ve attached the pastebins.

https://pastebin.com/7pdPG19c - EventsFeed.js

```
class EventsFeed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  async componentWillMount() {
    const eventId = this.props.match.params.id;
    await this.props.fetchEventInfo(eventId);
  /* fetching user's profile picture here */
    const hostId = this.props.selectedEvent.info.user_id;
    const userPhoto = await this.props.fetchUserImg(hostId);
  /* done fetching user's profile picture */ 
    await this.props.fetchUserInfo(sessionStorage.getItem('userId'));
  }
  onCreatePost() {
    const body = this.props.eventWallPost;
    const eventId = this.props.match.params.id;
    const authorId = sessionStorage.getItem('userId');
    this.props.createPostOnEventWall({ body, eventId, authorId}, this.props.fetchEventInfo);
  }
```

https://pastebin.com/knKyrjdr  - user_reducer.js

```
import { FETCH_USER_INFO, FETCH_USER_IMG } from '../actions/types';
const INITIAL_STATE = {}
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER_INFO:
      return action.payload.data;
    case FETCH_USER_IMG:
      return action.payload.data;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

https://pastebin.com/Enf2Pc6p - user_actions.js

```
export function fetchUserImg(userId) {
 async (dispatch) => {

   const response = await axios({
     method: 'get',
     url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/users/info',
     headers: {"id": userId}
   });

    return dispatch({ 
      type: FETCH_USER_IMG,
      payload: response.data.photo })
  };
}
```

https://pastebin.com/jCCF7TrS - types.js

```
export const FETCH_USER_IMG = 'fetch_user_img';
```

The Error when the page is loaded

```
   Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    4 stack frames were collapsed.
    EventsFeed._callee$
    src/EventsFeedPage/EventsFeed.js 31
      28 | 
      29 | /* fetching user's profile picture here */
      30 |   const hostId = this.props.selectedEvent.info.user_id;
    > 31 |   const userPhoto = await this.props.fetchUserImg(hostId);
      32 | /* done fetching user's profile picture */ 
      33 | 
      34 |   await this.props.fetchUserInfo(sessionStorage.getItem('userId'));
    View compiled
    5 stack frames were collapsed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says, you should use custom middleware which handles async actions, since by default actions must be plain objects.

For example, you can try this one: https://npmjs.com/package/redux-async-action
But if you need it just because of axios `redux-axios-middleware` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-axios-middleware) might do the work too.

Comment: but I see in our app.js that we already have thunk installed, isn't that the redux middleware?

Comment: By installed you mean you are using `thunk from 'redux-thunk'` and then `applyMiddleware(thunk)` inside the createStore function?

Comment: Another point, are you sure that `response.data.photo` is plain object and not a Promise? (https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/issues/146)

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import App from './App';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(promise, thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();

Comment: i did response.data.photo, the .photo because that's one of the key returned from the json

Comment: Hmm i actually did run into that link you posted, but I couldn't figure out how to implement that on my own...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `fetchUserImg` isn't returning anything. It has to return a function that receives dispatch as an argument:

```
export function fetchUserImg(userId) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6KyzqTE5     This is where I'm at.... am i on the right path? I'm not sure the proper way to dispatch the data this way.

Comment: You're on the right path, yep. Two things: while I think it's not *strictly* necessary, you should put a type on every action you dispatch. That's so you can differentiate them in your reducers. In your code, the last action you dispatch has no `type`. Second, be careful about mixing `await` with promises. When you do `const response = await axios(...)`, `response` won't be a promise. So you don't need `response.then` after that, you can just take `response.data` from it.